# How do I suspend and restart an existing worker thread instead of creating new ones?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna

I have a fairly simple question to ask to all the C# Multithreading gurus out there .. I'm making this multithreaded XNA game in which the `Update()` function is being performed in a separate thread (i.e. not in the main thread) .. The setup I've done is as follows:

This question assumes you know the significance of XNA specific game-oriented functions, such as `Update()`, `Draw()`, `LoadContent()`, etc ..

Right now this is what I'm doing:

In the `Update()` function, I have the following code:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
            //creating the thread
            updateThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateThreadRoutine));

        updateThread.Name = "UpdateThread";


        updateThread.Start(); //starting the thread

        updateFrameStart.Set(); //giving the signal to the new thread to start processing stuff ..

        updateFrameEnd.WaitOne(); // waiting for the new thread to signal back that its finished 

}
```

This is the code for the `UpdateThreadRoutine()` Function, which is executed by the newly created thread:

```
public void UpdateThreadRoutine()
{


updateFrameStart.WaitOne(); // wait for the signal from the main thread to start processing

//--> Doing all Updating stuff here <--

updateFrameEnd.Set();   //Signaling back to the main thread that updating process has finished ..

}
```

The problem is that once the `UpdateThreadRoutine()` finishes its processing, the created worker thread shuts down (destroys itself), which is why I'm currently being forced to explicitly define a new thread in every execution of the main `Update()` function ...

If I can find a way to make new thread NOT shutdown after its completed the `UpdateThreadRoutine()`, and instead just wait around or something, I can probably define the thread itself just once in the `LoadContent()` stage of the main thread ..

Again, I'm being forced to create a new thread in every loop of the main thread's `Update()` function, so that the new thread functions properly ..

Any ideas here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start the update thread ahead of time and just signal it when it's time to work:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    updateFrameStart.Set();
    updateFrameEnd.WaitOne();
}

public void UpdateThreadRoutine()
{
    while (!timeToQuit)
    {
        updateFrameStart.WaitOne();
        //--> Doing all Updating stuff here <--
        updateFrameEnd.Set();
    }
}
```

Let the thread loop forever until you tell it that it's time to quit.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using an extra thread at all? You're waiting for it to finish as soon as you start it, so it's not like you're achieving any parallelism.

You *could* write your own work queue, effectively - and have the thread wait for work to arrive. However, you'd be duplicating the job of the thread pool... any reason you *have* to create a new thread instead of just using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`?

Comment: Actually I am achieving parallelism as the code above is shrunk down .. There's some other stuff happening which I didn't mention above .. the Draw() part is also being executed with the Update code in a separate thread ..

Comment: I'm with Jon on this, the ThreadPool doesn't create new threads, it does exactly that which you need. Threads a kept around, waiting, and when work is completed, the thread is not terminated, it's returned to the pool and may continue some other work. The ThreadPool already services many of the asynchronous tasks done within the .NET Framework, so why roll your own? Might be good to know that these are background threads which the CLR can terminate if there are no, non-background threads running. The ThreadPool is's not means to keep your application running.

Comment: @Ahmad: Okay, in that case I go back to the ThreadPool idea. Could I suggest that in future you include more detail in the question, to make it sound more sensible? :)

Comment: I normally just try to include only details which really matter, so as to make it as simple for the reader as possible. But I understand you point too .. Will try to adhere to it :)